# Finding a function satisfying the integral relation

Tags: integration, integral-equations

Let $u$ be an absolutely continuous function on $(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}$. Find the unique absolutely continuous function $v$ satisfying,

$$ \int_a^bu(x)v(x)dx + \int_a^bu^\prime(x)v^\prime(x)dx = u(b) $$

I'm completely stumped on how to find a function like this. Initially I thought something simple like $v(x) = x$ would work out after integrating by parts, but unfortunately that did not work. I also tried a function like $v(x) = \int_0^xu^\prime(y)dy$, but this also didn't work.

Are there general techniques one can use to solve integral relations like this? Thanks.

Comment: If $int_{a}^{b} u(x)dx\neq 0$, we may take $v(x)=c$ where $c = u(b)/\int_{a}^{b}u(x)dx$.

Comment: Is the integral of $u$ on $[a,b]$ nonzero?

Comment: That is not specified, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we do integrate the second integral by parts, we find we want
$$ u(b) = u(b)v'(b)-u(a)v'(a) + \int_a^b u(x)(v(x)-v''(x)) \, dx. $$
We can satisfy this for any $u$ if we can find $v$ satisfying
$$ v'(b)=1, \qquad v'(a) = 0, \qquad v''-v = 0. $$
Staring at this for a bit, we realise that
$$ v(x) = \frac{\cosh{(x-a)}}{\sinh{(b-a)}} $$
will suffice.

I wouldn't go so far as to say that there are general techniques to deal with this type of problem, but it has a certain flavour of the calculus of variations to it, so that may be a source of applicable techniques in some cases.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I apologize for not stating this earlier, but the question intended to find a **unique solution**. It's actually related to the Reisz Representation Theorem. Is that feasible in this case?

Comment: I would have thought one could apply the usual idea of taking two solutions $v_1,v_2$ and considering the equation satisfied by $w=v_1-v_2$, i.e. $\int_a^b (u'w'+uw) = 0$. But the LHS is an inner product on the space of absolutely continuous functions, so it is only zero for all $u$ if $w \equiv 0$.